# TSQL: how to select a sentence by complex logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would you help me to select a sentence by complex logic.
Platform: TSQL.

Initial data:

| sentence | result |
| --- | --- |
| company "Apple corp" has an apple on its logotype | 1 |
| company "Apple computers" is a large company | 0 |
| Apple company | 1 |

conditions:

1. must have %Apple%
2. not take into account %"%Apple%"%
   This means: if the sentence has only %"%Apple%"%, condition not met
   But if the sentence has both %Apple% AND %"%Apple%"% - condition met

I tried to apply some kinds of logic:
First:

1. Substitute the word "Apple" with some rare symbol. Eg. "|"
2. Delete in the sentence all the symbols but | and quotes
3. To look for the "|" symbol and to look left and right from it. If the quote is absent on one of the sides, condition met.

Second:
Split the sentence on the basis of the word Apple

Third:
Split the sentence on the basis of the quotes

But I whether don't know how to technically fulfill the logic, or the logic doesn't meet the goal.

Comment: Why are you using SQL for this? SQL is probably the worst language for text-processing.

Comment: Use a language that (fully) support Regex; T-SQL has no support for Regex.

Comment: I would do this by python. But initial data is in MSSQL Server. It is not the quickest solution to move the data processing from SQL to python and back.

Comment: Agreed with earlier comments.  Can you go the database and just get "like %Apple%" rows... (do you have 100 of these or 10 million?).........and write the detailed "rules" in a middle tier component?

Comment: granadaCoder, I have thousands of rows. Each row is a comment written by the client by hand. Therefore it may contain '"Apple"', 'Apple', 'Apple"', '"Apple', '"Apple Apple"', '"Apple"Apple"', 'Apple"Apple"' and other combinations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use sql, just use multiple conditions in your WHERE clause. This way, you don't have to call a function for replacements or other manipulations.

You can rephrase your conditions like this:

- Text contains only Apple but not "Apple"
  OR
- Text contains both Apple and "Apple"

  - Possibility 1: First apple, then "apple"
  - Possibility 2: First "apple", then apple

```
WHERE
(Col LIKE '%apple%' AND Col NOT LIKE '%"%apple%"%') -- APPLE, but not "APPLE"
OR Col LIKE '%apple%"%apple%"%'                     -- APPLE .. "APPLE" ..
OR Col LIKE '%"%apple%"%apple%'                     -- "APPLE" .. APPLE ..
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa90291d4fe5b9f37bd33a557cddc3cb)

Comment: Stephan Bauer, thank you for solution, but it doesn't completely meet the goal since both the constructions: '%apple%' and  '%"%apple%"%' may present in the sentence. This means we do not have to exclude all the sentences with '%"%apple%"%' construction. We have to not take it into account.

Comment: If *both* constructions are included in the text, the second or the third condition will be met

Comment: Stephan Bauer, thank you for the example, but it selects the sentence 'company "Apple" apple" computers" is a large company' while it doesn't have to. Since both the words in the sentence are covered with quotes. And it doesn't select the sentence 'company "Apple apple computers" is a large company' while it does have to. Since none of the words in the sentence are covered with quotes from the left and from the right.

Comment: Alright then the second condition in the question is (at least for me) misleading or at least not precise enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data and explanation *appears* to just require the following, does this work for you?

```
with d as (
 select 'company "Apple corp" has an apple on its logotype  1' sentence union
 select 'company "Apple computers" is a large company   0' union
 select 'Apple company'
)
select * , case when Replace(Replace(sentence,'"apple',''),'apple"','') like '%apple%' then 1 else 0 end
from d;
```

Comment: Stu, thank you so much. Your solution is close to the goal, but it mark as 1 the sentence 'company "Apple" apple" computers" is a large company', while it doesn't have to. Since both the words Apple are covered with quotes.

Comment: @AlexIvanov ok, that's not sample data in your question, but perhaps using a nested replace to take care of both opening and closing quotes? I have amended answer above, can you review? Hopefully it gives you enough and you can tweak for any other edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by applying this logic.

1. Substitute Apple with '|'
2. Delete from the sentence all characters but '|' and '"'
3. Substitute '"' with '""'. To handle the cases where one quote belongs to 2 words '"Apple"Apple"'
4. Delete from the sentence all characters '|' covered with quotes.
5. Select the sentence which contain '|'

First, we should create the function for point 2.

```
create function [dbo].[fn_KeepCharacters](@String varchar(2000), @KeepValues varchar(255))
returns varchar(2000)
as
begin

    set @KeepValues = '%['+@KeepValues+']%'
    while patindex(@KeepValues, @String) > 0
        set @String = stuff(@String, patindex(@KeepValues, @String), 1, '')

    return @String
end

go
```

Full code:

```
with d as (
 select 'big company "Apple"' col 
  union select 'Apple, start' 
  union select 'comp Apple" computers'
  union select  'inc " int Apple ap' 
  union select '"i Apple""mac Apple" aa' 
  union select 'book "pen Apple"pineApple"' 
  union select 'leaf Apple"Apple"'
)
--, b as (
select col, case when replace(replace(dbo.fn_KeepCharacters(replace(col, 'Apple', '|'), '^"|'), '"', '""'), '"|"', '""') 
like '%|%' then 1 else null end
 col_sec
from d
```

I give thanks to stackoverflow members for help. Especially, to @Stu for nested replace advice.

The problem, that fn_KeepCharacters contains while circle which is very slow. I will appreciate the faster solutions.